# Trying to passing and accessing data to Livewire modal in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm using Laravel 10 with Livewire 3, and I'm trying to pass data to a modal component through a button click with the following code:

Button code to trigger the display of the modal in `my-component.blade.php`:

```html
<button wire:click="$dispatch('open-modal', 'show-location', {lat:{{ $item->location->latitude }}, lon:{{ $item->location->longitude }}})">
<x-icon-o-map-pin class="h-4 w-4" />
</button>

<x-modal name="show-location" :show="$errors->isNotEmpty()" focusable>
    <p>Latitude: {{ $locationData['lat'] }}</p>
    <p>Longitude: {{ $locationData['lon'] }}</p>
</x-modal>
```

Modal component:

```php
@props([
    'name',
    'show' => false,
    'maxWidth' => '2xl'
])

@php
$maxWidth = [
    'sm' => 'sm:max-w-sm',
    'md' => 'sm:max-w-md',
    'lg' => 'sm:max-w-lg',
    'xl' => 'sm:max-w-xl',
    '2xl' => 'sm:max-w-2xl',
][$maxWidth];
@endphp

<div
    x-data="{
        show: @js($show),
        focusables() {
            // All focusable element types...
            let selector = 'a, button, input:not([type=\'hidden\']), textarea, select, details, [tabindex]:not([tabindex=\'-1\'])'
            return [...$el.querySelectorAll(selector)]
                // All non-disabled elements...
                .filter(el => ! el.hasAttribute('disabled'))
        },
        firstFocusable() { return this.focusables()[0] },
        lastFocusable() { return this.focusables().slice(-1)[0] },
        nextFocusable() { return this.focusables()[this.nextFocusableIndex()] || this.firstFocusable() },
        prevFocusable() { return this.focusables()[this.prevFocusableIndex()] || this.lastFocusable() },
        nextFocusableIndex() { return (this.focusables().indexOf(document.activeElement) + 1) % (this.focusables().length + 1) },
        prevFocusableIndex() { return Math.max(0, this.focusables().indexOf(document.activeElement)) -1 },
    }"
    x-init="$watch('show', value => {
        if (value) {
            document.body.classList.add('overflow-y-hidden');
            {{ $attributes->has('focusable') ? 'setTimeout(() => firstFocusable().focus(), 100)' : '' }}
        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove('overflow-y-hidden');
        }
    })"
    x-on:open-modal.window="$event.detail == '{{ $name }}' ? show = true : null"
    x-on:close.stop="show = false"
    x-on:keydown.escape.window="show = false"
    x-on:keydown.tab.prevent="$event.shiftKey || nextFocusable().focus()"
    x-on:keydown.shift.tab.prevent="prevFocusable().focus()"
    x-show="show"
    class="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto px-4 py-6 sm:px-0 z-50"
    style="display: {{ $show ? 'block' : 'none' }};"
>
    <div
        x-show="show"
        class="fixed inset-0 transform transition-all"
        x-on:click="show = false"
        x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300"
        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0"
        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100"
        x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200"
        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0"
    >
        <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 dark:bg-gray-900 opacity-75"></div>
    </div>

    <div
        x-show="show"
        class="mb-6 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:w-full {{ $maxWidth }} sm:mx-auto"
        x-transition:enter="ease-out duration-300"
        x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
        x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
        x-transition:leave="ease-in duration-200"
        x-transition:leave-start="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
        x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
    >
        {{ $slot }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Livewire component where the modal and the button in:

```php
class MyComponent extends Component
{
    public $locationData;

    #[On('open-modal')]
    public function openModalData($message)
    {
        $this->locationData = $message;
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code, I receive the error message "Trying to access array offset on the value of type null." How can I resolve this issue and successfully pass data to the modal component in Livewire?

Comment: Maybe you want to use *$dispatchTo* instead of *$dispatch*? *$dispatch* accepts only 2 parameters (and *$dispatchTo* wants the *otherComponentName* as first  parameter). According to the code you posted, the only places where the error can occour are in *$locationData['lat']* and in *$locationData['lon']*. You should post the full error and possibly the full code.

Comment: @Pippo I've tried what you suggested using $dispatchTo, but my modal component won't show up. I've edited my question by adding the modal component code.

Comment: Yes, but the third parameter of *$dispatch* will be probably lost. Check if *function openModalData()* is triggered, then check the *$message* parameter

Comment: When you `dd($message)` in your modal, what is the result? Does it show the passed data?